# Custom Arquillian ArquillianResteasyResource application path- Error HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, resteasy, jboss-arquillian

My REST API works fine when deployed but my tests are failing using Jersey Arquillian extension:

```java
@Test
@RunAsClient
public void postTest(@ArquillianResteasyResource final WebTarget webTarget) {

    MyRequest request = new MyRequest();

    String response = webTarget.path("/demo").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.json(request)).readEntity(String.class);

    Assert.assertEquals("OK", response);

}
```

I get the error:

```
Error HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

My JAX-RS programs look OK:

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

}

@Path("/demo")
@Stateless
public class DemoResource extends BaseResource {

    @POST
    public Response demo(MyRequest request) {
        return Response.ok().entity("OK").build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for `@ArquillianResteasyResource` is `rest`, but my JaxRsActivator is set to `api`.

To solve it I used:

```
@ArquillianResteasyResource("api")
```

To get the complete URI: `webTarget.getUri()`